# How do I know how many result pages can I get using python-twitter GetSearch() method

Tags: python, twitter, python-twitter

I use twitter-python search API to retrieve search results like below

```
import twitter
api = twitter.Api()
i = 1
result = api.GetSearch("Avatar", page=i)
print [s.text for s in result]
```

The code above means I want to get the result on first page returned. I tried multiple assignment of i they all work. But I don't know what is the maxium value of i can I assign. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum value is going to depend on the query, and how many pages twitter feels like giving you.

What about using try/except?

```
import twitter
api = twitter.Api()

# try a large page number:
i = 181

try:
    result = api.GetSearch("Avatar", page=i)
    print [s.text for s in result]
except:
    print 'page is out of range'
```